# Left Adjoint to the Forgetful Functor on $\lambda$-rings?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ct.category-theory, lambda-rings

The forgetful functor from the category of $\lambda$-rings to that of rings has a right adjoint in the form of the universal $\lambda$ functor $\Lambda$, which is isomorphic to the big Witt vectors functor.  But, does the forgetful functor have a left adjoint?  Some kind of free $\lambda$-ring functor?

EDIT: I see this as obviously true when I forget all the way down to sets.  But, I only want to forget down to the category of commutative rings.  Would it just be to take the free ring on all the elements, mod out by the $\lambda$ relations and all the ring relations?

Comment: This is obviously true from the definition of a lambda ring as a commutative ring with operators and certain relations among these operators.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The edit suggests to me that you want not only the *existence* of the free $\lambda$-ring on any given ring (which is immediate from general results about adjoints of forgetful functors between varieties of algebras) but a construction using terms.  Given a ring R, first form the set of all formal $\lambda$-ring terms over $R$, i.e., well-formed expressions built from the operations of $\lambda$-rings (the ring operations and the $\lambda$'s) and symbols for all the elements of $R$.  Then divide out by the equivalence relation that identifies two such terms if their equality is provable (in equational logic) from the axioms of $\lambda$-rings plus the diagram of $R$.  (For the diagram, it suffices to take all those equations that are true in $R$ and have the form $a+b=c$ or $ab=c$, where $a,b,c$ are among the symbols for elements of $R$.)

What I've written here is, of course, not specific to $\lambda$-rings.  The left adjoint of any forgetful functor between varieties of algebras can be constructed in an analogous way.

Comment: Quite belatedly - [the nlab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lambda-ring#FreeAndCofreeLambdaRings) on $\lambda$-rings mentions that the forgetful functor from $\lambda$-rings to commutative rings has both left and right adjoints, given, respectively, by symmetric functions and Witt vectors. Papers of Hazewinkel and Borger, both around 2008 are cited, although I believe this was known before - at least about the right adjoint I learned much earlier from a talk by Joyal.